# Using .htaccess file to change php version makes pages downloadable

Tags: php, .htaccess, version-control, permissions

I'm using a host whose default PHP version is 5.2.9 and I need to change it to 5.3.x for one folder that takes advantage of namespaces (5.2.x does not support them). I know this can be done by putting the following directive

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php
```

in the .htaccess file of that folder, but when I do that it downloads the php file instead of executing it. I found one other question like this on the site, but it didn't help and wasn't completely relevant to my situation.

Comment: Using this Apache directive won't work if `PHP 5.3.x` is **not** installed on your server.

Comment: Is this directive recommended by the host? TBH, your host would be the one to check this with - it could depend on your server config exactly what directive works for you.

Answer (score -1):

You guys were right, my host does not have that version of php. Not much I can do except switch hosts.